# ProtectionLevel after rooting

Tags: android, rooted-device

AFAIK, there doesn't seem to be any way to get permission for ProtectionLevel=3 without rooting the phone. I have searched high and low, and everywhere I look, I see the same answer: "It can't be done." However, ProxyDroid does it, and so do some other applications that I have seen on the market.

However, these applications ask for root privileges. So my question thus is, can we get these permissions after rooting them?

I am trying to get permission for WRITE_SECURE_SETTING. However I always get the following error:

```
08-05 21:19:04.372: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1117): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```